# mongodb inserting subdocuments as : [Object]

Tags: node.js, mongodb

i am inserting data into `mongodb` using `mongodb` driver in `nodejs`.

```
var mongodb = require('mongodb');

var insert = function(uri, collectionName, data, next) {
    mongodb.MongoClient.connect(uri, function(err, driverDb) {  
      if(err) {
        next(err);
      } else {
        driverDb.collection(collectionName).insert(data,function(err,result) {
            if(err) {
                next(err);
            } else {
                driverDb.close(function (err) {
                    if(err) {
                        next(err);
                    } else {
                        next(null,result);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
      }
    });
};


insert('mongodb://localhost/mean-test','testcol',{ 
             a : 'Apple',
             b : [ { ba: 'Boy' }, {bb : 'Bird'} ]
        }, function(err,models) {
            console.log(models);
        });
```

The above result into following:

```
[{a:'Apple', b : [[Object]] }]
```

How do i achieve this :

```
[{_id:ObjectId("someid"), a:'Apple', b : [{_id:ObjectId("someid"), ba: 'Boy' }, {_id:ObjectId("someid"), bb : 'Bird'}] }]
```

Please note i do not want to use any other npm module except of `mongodb`.
also i want to insert in one db query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your objects are inserting correctly, it's just that `console.log` only shows two levels of object detail by default.  To show all object levels you need to call [`util.inspect`](http://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_inspect_object_options) directly so you can control that:

```
console.log(util.inspect(models, {depth: null}));
```

Comment: when i console.log(models[0].b[0]._id), i get undefined. why so?

Comment: Your `b` array elements won't have `_id` properties until you manually include them in the object you're passing to `insert`.